# How to download Collection of Mongo from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, download

I have Mongo Database, and I would like to download all register of one collection using NodeJs API. I would like to download like a CSV or something like it. At the moment I have 501426 register of my collection, so when I call to .find() method it returns this error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
[15092:000001FE5E775B70]    95966 ms: Mark-sweep 1407.6 (1467.7) -> 1407.5 
(1451.2) MB, 1408.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[15092:000001FE5E775B70]    97421 ms: Mark-sweep 1407.5 (1451.2) -> 1407.5 
(1451.2) MB, 1454.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
<--- JS stacktrace --->
==== JS stack trace =========================================
Security context: 000003F5F89A5EE1 <JSObject>
2: GetHash(aka GetHash) [native collection.js:1] [bytecode=000003F5F89D1721 
offset=51](this=0000011364082311 <undefined>,o=000002F6E28FAE89 <JSFunction 
wrapper (sfi = 000003167E337821)>)
4: set [native weak-collection.js:1] [bytecode=000003167E3380F9 offset=50]
(this=000001DB08591699 <JSWeakMap>,key=000002F6E28FAE89 <JSFunction wrapper 
(sfi = 000003167E337821)>,value=00000021B54F67F9 <J...
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

My code is this:

```
Collection.find({}).then(function(logs) {
  res.charset = 'utf-8';
          res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 'filename.csv');
          res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/csv');
          csv
            .write(logs, {
              headers: true,
              transform: function(row) {
                return {
                  'Nivel': row.level,
                  'Metodo': row.method,
                  'IP': row.ip,
                  'URL': row.url,
                  'Status Code': row['status-code'],
                  'Usuario': row.user_email.email,
                  'Fecha': row.createdAt,
                  'Cuerpo': row.req_body,
                  'Consulta': row.req_query,
                  'Navegador': row['user-agent'],
                  'Datos Usuario': row.user_email,
                  'Aplicacion': row.referrer
                };
              }
            })
            .pipe(res);
})
```

This code works, but I would like to download all documents of Collection. Sorry about my english.

Thanks

Comment: There are no real "models" in mongoDB. Its dynamic by nature. Are you talking about "documents" in a "collection" ? And please show your code, that would help a lot ;)

Comment: Thanks @JonasW. and sorry about my question! I changed it

Comment: Okay, next question: which library does `csv` refer to?

Comment: @JonasW. it is csv = require('fast-csv'); :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of transforming/ parsing the memory all at once, you should rather process one after another. For that we need a Stream first we can write the data to:

```
 var csvStream = csv.createWriteStream({headers: true}),
csvStream.pipe(res); // directly pipe it to the user
```

Then we can read the collection document by document, and pipe it to the csv Transformer:

```
 Collection.find({}).stream({
    transform(row){
      return {
              'Nivel': row.level,
              'Metodo': row.method,
              'IP': row.ip,
              'URL': row.url,
              'Status Code': row['status-code'],
              'Usuario': row.user_email.email,
              'Fecha': row.createdAt,
              'Cuerpo': row.req_body,
              'Consulta': row.req_query,
              'Navegador': row['user-agent'],
              'Datos Usuario': row.user_email,
              'Aplicacion': row.referrer
            };
    }
  }).pipe(csvStream);
```